# Bash script behaving differently for different files

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that uses awk to process some files that I have downloaded. If I run the script on any of the files it does not work properly. However, if I transfer the contents of a file in a newly created one it seems to work as supposed. Could it have anything to do with the settings of the files?

I have two files file hotel_12313.dat and hotel_99999.dat . The first one is downloaded and the second one is created by me. If I copy the data from the first file into the second one and I execute the script on both of them the output is different.

Comment: Clarify your question. It is not clean enough.

Comment: It could be the lineending convention used in the files. Check with your editor if one is e.g DOS/Windows and the other is e.g. Unix.

Comment: When I copy paste the text into a file that I have created the script works appropriately.

Comment: As Lars Fischer already said: line endings can be an issue. If you use a text editor and copy/paste from file A to B or from file B to A the text editor may silently "repair" line endings when pasting. (I know that XEmacs does it.) If you want to be sure what really is in your files you may use for example `hexdump`.

Comment: Use Shellcheck to check compatibility. http://www.shellcheck.net/